# How to use xr.open_mfdataset on files that have a non-monotonic time dimension

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netCDF files ('U.*.nc') that have non-monotonic time coordindates (restarting for each file). I would like to read them using xr.open_dataset('U.*.nc'). However, it throws the error below.

ValueError: Coordinate variable time is neither monotonically increasing nor monotonically decreasing on all datasets

Is there a way to tell xarray not to worry about the non-monotonicity?